# Customizable way to instantiate objects in 1 expression in C++

Tags: c++, builder

In Rust, there is this [crate](https://github.com/colin-kiegel/rust-derive-builder) which utilize Rust procedural macro to automatically implement builder pattern for any arbitrary struct defined. As there is no flexible way to instantiate Rust struct with some default and some provided values, this helps a lot in reducing boilerplate.

Is there any similar thing to generate builders automatically in C++, as instantiating objects in C++ also requires a lot of boilerplate (a lot of overloaded constructors to cover all posible combinations of fields or multiple steps initialization), possibly using C/C++ macros?

As the comments suggested, I added an example to clarify my idea. I want to instantiate class A below by just provide some field I want and leave others as default. If so, I either have to implement a lot of constructors or do multiple steps, instantiate and then override fields I want:

- Multiple constructors

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  int a = 2;
  std::string b = "b";
  int c = 5;
  std::string d = "d";
  A() {}
  A(int a) { this->a = a; }
  A(std::string b) { this->b = b; }
  A(int a, std::string b)
  {
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
  }
  // ... more constructors to cover all combinations
  // this might not even work as some combinations might
  // have similar types, which prevent overloading them
};
```

- Multiple steps

```cpp
A a;
a.b = "hello";
a.c = 10;
```

Multiple steps instantiation is actually nice. However, it does not work if I want to have customized instantiation in 1 expression.
With builder pattern, I do that in 1 expression by chaining methods like this:

```cpp
BuilderOfA()
  .a(7)
  .c(8)
  .build();
```

Can the definition of this builder be automatically generated at compile time in C++? If not, is there anyway I can instantiate an object in a customizable way (by just provide some field I want and leave others as default) without using multiple expressions?

Comment: The term "builder pattern" itself is very ambiguous. What _exactly_ are you **really** wanting to do and why do you think it will help you write better code?

Comment: There is no such thing in the core C++ language itself. Various C++ development tools may offer some automation for created some boilerplate, but it varies by tool and tool or software recommendations are not appropriate questions for Stackoverflow, sorry.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think the OP is asking for a tool or lib recommendation, they're just asking if _stock_ C++ can do it in-box - in which case the answer is "yes, but only if you want to reason about thousands of lines of variadic template fun!"

Comment: I'm personally not a huge fan of (most kinds of) "builder" types and patterns I see (no matter the language: C++, TypeScript, C#, or the worst: Java...). What's wrong with good ol' fashioned constructors?

Comment: XY-Problem - _"...a lot of overloaded constructors to cover all possible combinations of fields ..."_ if you can't clearly state the class invariants and then write the necessary constructor(s) that enforces them; you have a design problem not a code or tool-automation problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rust so it is hard to tell what is your expectation. In C++ there are many tricks to avoid providing lots of different overloads. It is impossible to tell what you need without real example.

Comment: You can have default values in structs. Also list initialization exist and you don't need to initialize the whole struct with a list initializer, so if you put the members which tend to be default all at the end it can be fairly convenient to initialize the struct to what you want in many cases.

Comment: Hi everyone, I have updated my question with an example to clarify my idea and my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ 20 you can do this:

```
struct S {
    std::string str = "Hello";
    float y = 1.0f;
    int x = 10;
};

auto a = S{ .str = "Hi", .x = 8 };
```

Comment: I got `error: designator order for field ‘S::str’ does not match declaration order in ‘S’` trying to compile this. It should be in the correct order: `auto s = S{.str = "Hi", .x = 8};`

Comment: Whoops. You still need to match the order in the class. I added a string to show that it will construct the members if an appropriate constructor exist and forgot to respect the order when I did that.

Comment: Oh. And I confirm this code compiles even on c++14